# Flutter Getx and ScreenUtility Not Work Together

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have problem with ScreenUtility and GetMaterialApp.
When i use GetMaterialApp and ScreenUtility together i got some error.
When i build apk release, in first open evertyhing seems normal, but when close apk and open again, my widgets are disappering.

`void main() {
WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
runApp(ScreenUtilInit(
designSize: const Size(375, 812),
builder: () => GetMaterialApp(

```
  theme: ThemeData(
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        subtitle1: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        subtitle2: RegisterPageConstansts.textFieldHintStyle,
      ),
      fontFamily: "Avenir"),
  home: const OnboardingScreen(),
),
```

));
FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
}`

Comment: Format the whole code .